# Proper handling of DomainOperationException

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, wcf-ria-services

In my Silverlight application I want properly handle different server errors.
I created handler for [`DomainOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.domainoperationexception%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) but there I want to get more specific information about root cause of a problem and provide more clear messages for user.

*Possible ways to do this:*

- `OperationStatus` gives me some advantages, but still mostly all
  errors that are connected to server have `OperationStatus.ServerError` whether it is DB or IIS issue;
- Exception also has `ErrorCode` property, but I don't know where to get list of  possible error codes that will be suitable with RIA;

NOTE: Even without setting `ErrorCode` by myself it has value 500 when issue with DB connection occurs on server side. That's why I'm hoping that RIA is doing all dirty work, and I will avoid doing this redundant effort.

---

*Questions:*

1. What is the best way to properly handle
   `DomainOperationException`?
2. Where to get possible error codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ErrorCode` is a user-defined value. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.domainoperationexception.errorcode%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) states that it

> Gets or sets the custom error code for this exception. The error code can be any user-defined value.

Probably there are more elegant solutions but what I ended up doing is to create a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) (but you can use a .shared classes too) where I defined an `enum` with my error codes. I referenced that project in the server-side and the client side projects.

I then overrode the DomainService's `OnError`-method and did something like this:

```
 protected override void OnError(DomainServiceErrorInfo errorInfo)
 {
     if (errorInfo.Error is UnauthorizedAccessException)
     {
         errorInfo.Error = new DomainException("Denied access.",(int)MyErrorCodesEnum.Permission_Unauthorized, errorInfo.Error);
     }
 }
```

(Looking at this code it makes me want to create kind of an associative list of exception types and enumerator values so I can drop the `if` but you get the idea)

On client-side I do:

```
switch ((MyErrorCodesEnum)(s.Error as DomainException).ErrorCode)
{
    case MyErrorCodesEnum.Permission_Unauthorized:
        //do something
        s.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        break;
}
```

Comment: I prefer shared enums for this purposes. Works well.